# Add a prefix to each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table with this as name of the columns :

```
Name, Birthday, Year, Size
```

And I want to add a prefix to every column like this:

```
NY_Name, NY_Birthday, NY_Year, NY_Size
```

Obviously I have more columns than these 4, so this is the reason why I ask you for a query - how to add a prefix to column names with SQL Server?

Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: This appears to be an XY problem where you are making columns specific to something. Probably not the best approach and could be done better.

Comment: `SELECT Name AS NY_Name, Birthday AS NY_Birthday`?

Comment: `EXEC sp_RENAME '[TableName].[OldColumnName]', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to rename the columns in the table permanently, or just give them an alias when you select them in a query? Also _why_ do you want to do this, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to generate a script from the table catalog (SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'), using the following procedure [sp_rename (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

for example:

```
USE DB;  
GO  
EXEC sp_rename 'Table.Name', 'NY_Name', 'COLUMN';  
GO
```

Comment: Does _Add prefix_ mean _rename_?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it would be to use dynamic SQL, but try to avoid doing that if you can help it.

Here's one way:

```
/* --create table to test

CREATE TABLE dbo.WTF (
    Name VARCHAR(10), 
    Birthday VARCHAR(10), 
    Year VARCHAR(10), 
    Size VARCHAR(10)
)

*/

DECLARE @prefix VARCHAR(10) = 'NY_'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) = N'';
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(1000) = '';

SELECT  @columns = @columns + c.name + ' ' + QUOTENAME(@prefix + c.name) + ',
'
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'WTF'
ORDER BY c.column_id

set @columns = left(@columns, len(@columns) - 3) --remove last comma and cr lf

set @sql = N'SELECT
' + @columns + '
FROM dbo.WTF'

select @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

This returns:

```
SELECT
Name [NY_Name],
Birthday [NY_Birthday],
Year [NY_Year],
Size [NY_Size]
FROM dbo.WTF

NY_Name    NY_Birthday NY_Year    NY_Size
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
```

Good luck!